# How to make RecyclerView repeat the list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have `ArrayList` 1,2,3,4... All what im trying to do is, when you scroll the list and last row is shown - repeat the list, like 1,2,3,4...1,2,3,4...1,2,3,4 and do it infinite times.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from `Adapter#getItemCount` method to make it "infinite"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to scroll back? If you don't, I think when you scroll last item, then you can scroll to the first item.

Otherwise, you should have a data set that `RecyclerView` will render.
When scrolled to last item, add the array(1,2,3,4...) to the dataSet, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by pskink you can return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in Adapters `getItemCount`. Than change the value of position received by `onBindViewHolder()` like this:

```
int realPosition = position % arrayList.size();
```

Then use new value wherever you would use position.